# Async/await function is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I'm new to using async/await and from my understanding, I can declare the function as an asynchronous function and then use await inside of that function.

What I would like for my code to do is to run `document.getElementById('PrePayeezyForm').submit()` only after the `updateNewInvoice` function has completed. `UpdateNewInvoice` function is setting data to my Redux store and I have a form that is referring to the data from the store.

The issue is, the last line is running so quickly that the form is referring to empty data in the store before it is set. If I use a `setTimeout`, it works but I don't want to have to do that. Thanks for the help.

```
import styles from './styles.module.scss'

const FormPayeezy = ({
  payeezyArray,
  removeInvoiceModal,
  updateNewInvoice,
  updatePO,
  customer
}) => {

  async function updateNewInvoices(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    //save amount to redux and generate form values
    let amount = event.target.x_amount.value
    let customer = event.target.customer.value
    await updateNewInvoice(amount, customer)
    document.getElementById('PrePayeezyForm').submit();
  }

  function updatePOs(event) {
    //save PO to redux
    updatePO(event.target.value)
  }

  function hideModal(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    removeInvoiceModal()
  }

  return (
    <form id="PrePayeezyForm" className={styles.addInvoiceForm} method="post" action="https://demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/payment" onSubmit={updateNewInvoices}>
      <input name="x_login" value={payeezyArray.login} type="hidden" />
      <input name="x_invoice_num" value={payeezyArray.payment_num} type="hidden" />
      <input name="x_fp_sequence" value={payeezyArray.sequence} type="hidden" />
      <input name="x_fp_timestamp" value={payeezyArray.timestamp} type="hidden" />
      <input name="x_fp_hash" value={payeezyArray.hash} type="hidden" />
      <input name="x_show_form" value="PAYMENT_FORM" type="hidden" />
      <input name="x_relay_response" value="TRUE" type="hidden" />
      <label>Payment Description</label>
      <input type="text" required name="loadNum" id="loadNum" onBlur={updatePOs} />
      <label>Payment Amount</label>
      <input type="text" required name="x_amount" id="x_amount" />
      <input required name="customer" id="customer" value={customer} type="hidden" />
      {payeezyArray.items}
      <button className={styles.buttonAdd} type="submit"
      >Pay Invoice</button>
      <button className={styles.buttonCancel}
        onClick={hideModal}
      >Cancel</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default FormPayeezy

//////////////////////////////////////////

  updateNewInvoice = async (amount, customerid) => {
    const { updatePayeezyCustomer, updatePayeezyAmount } = this.props
    updatePayeezyAmount(amount)
    updatePayeezyCustomer(customerid)
    let loadid = this.props.payeezyArray.PO
    let note = `New Invoice for PO #: ${loadid}`
    let paymentInfo = {
      'other': [
        {
          customerid,
          note,
          amount: Number(amount)
        }
      ]
    }
    this.props.getPaymentResponse(paymentInfo, (id) => {
      this.props.updatePayeezyPaymentNum(id)
    })
    let timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
    this.props.updatePayeezyTimestamp(timestamp)
    let hash = createPayeezyHash(this.props.payeezyArray, timestamp, amount)
    this.props.updatePayeezyHash(hash)
    let value = `${this.props.payeezyArray.PO}<|><|>PO ${this.props.payeezyArray.PO}<|>1<|>${amount}<|>N`
    let content = <input name="x_line_item" value={value} type="hidden"></input>
    this.props.updatePayeezyItems(content)
  }
```

Comment: "only after the updateNewInvoice function has completed" --- that's what actually happens. If you still have a problem - it's somewhere else.

Comment: Could you paste the code for the entire async function including how you declared it? Showing the code for the entire component could also be helpful

Comment: I've updated the code so you have more context

Comment: It looks like you're not using `await` inside of `updateNewInvoice` anywhere. Is it possible that `updatePayeezyAmount` & `updatePayeezyCustomer` are asynchronous functions? and/or some other item inside of `updateNewInvoice` that needs to be waited on?

Comment: `this.props.getPaymentResponse` looks asynchronous - it has a clalback - you're not waiting for that to run - and besides that, why is `updateNewInvoice` async if you never await in it? seems like an odd (yet all too common) thing to do